# Bootstrap - if first column is higher than others, last column doesn't layout correctly (fiddle example)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i need to make a nice column layout that would be responsive and would layout nicely, but there is a problem, if first column has longer text, last column jumps to 2nd column, well it's hard to explain, here is a sample:

http://jsfiddle.net/LmL1a549/

HTML:

```
<div id="block1" class="col-xs-4"><p>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test </p></div>

<div id="block2" class="col-xs-4"><p>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test </p></div>

<div id="block3" class="col-xs-4"><p>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test </p></div>

<div id="block4" class="col-xs-4"><p>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test </p></div>
```

Green column should be below grey column, i think the best way to fix this would be to somehow make all columns the same height, but i can't use fixed height because it must be responsive. Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clear the floats after .block3

```
<div id="block1" class="col-xs-4"><p>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test </p></div>

<div id="block2" class="col-xs-4"><p>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test </p></div>

<div id="block3" class="col-xs-4"><p>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test </p></div>

<div class="clearfix"></div>

<div id="block4" class="col-xs-4"><p>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test </p></div>
```

You have the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/LmL1a549/2/

Comment: Thank you, this is the best answer. Others weren't as sufficient, I can't use row, because 3 row layout with 4-4 divs was just an example, actually in this case I don't even know how many rows will there be, because it will be editable by users dynamically. I think clearfix will do it, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap has 12 columns per row. Your fourth column will always be in the next row and by default it will be below the shortest column, which is why it isn't below your first column but the second.

Instead wrap your `column` divs in a `row` div, making sure that each row contains no more than 12 columns at any size if you want to avoid this behaviour. You should look at the [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) for more examples of how to use the grid layout

Corrected [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LmL1a549/3)

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap have 12 columns per row, so if you use col-xs-4 four times you get 16 colums, so change your code like this:

```
<div class="row">

<div id="block1" class="col-xs-3"><p>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test </p></div>

<div id="block2" class="col-xs-3"><p>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test </p></div>

<div id="block3" class="col-xs-3"><p>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test </p></div>

<div id="block4" class="col-xs-3"><p>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test </p></div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LmL1a549/6/

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily by wrapping the first 3 DIVa in a single DIV with a `class="row"`

Have a look at this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LmL1a549/9/)

```
<div class="row">
    <div id="block1" class="col-xs-4"><p>test test test</p></div>
    <div id="block2" class="col-xs-4"><p>test</p></div>
    <div id="block3" class="col-xs-4"><p>test </p></div>
</div>
<div id="block4" class="col-xs-4"><p>test</p></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the clearfix class directly in the column's i.e.

```
<div id="block3" class="col-xs-4 clearfix"></div>
```

This should solve your issue